# Yahoo finance historical API csv cannot seem to openstream? JAVA

Tags: java, csv, yahoo-finance

```
//URL url =  new URL("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv");
URL url =  new URL("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=&b=3&c=2017&d=4&e=1&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv");
URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
System.out.println(urlConn.getInputStream().available());
```

Working in java.

The first url which returns today's data in csv format works fine, returns 70 bytes.

However, the second url which return a list of historical data in csv  returns 0 bytes. This url works fine if opened via browser.

What's the difference and how to make it work?

(I've also tried urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.10; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0")

Comment: The second URL **redirects** (301) from http: **to https:**, as you can see by looking at the statuscode and headers instead of only the body. A browser will follow this redirect but HttpUrlConnection does not. Issue the request with https: and you'll get the data. The first URL doesn't do this. I remember seeing a very similar Q a day or two ago, but I can't find the dupe now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, forgot to mention I tried https already. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo has disabled automation usage of their finance script so it will only work in browser. I found an alternative with Java's Desktop library.